# Automotive voltage specifications

Tags: automotive

I've been tasked with designing a circuit (actually a buck/boost converter outputting 20 Volts at up to 10 Amps) which takes "automotive voltage".  This product will be subject to some sort of official automotive certification.  Nobody at my company is currently able to tell me exactly what that means.  We're going for cost, and it needs to be integrated into our PCB, so yes I'm looking at using certain TI chips, discretes, etc.  Like a normal dc/dc supply, not a module to purchase.

Can someone give me the brief summary on what "automotive voltage" looks like?  I've been told it can go as low as 6 volts, but nothing so far in terms of spikey transients, picking up noise from other junk under the hood, etc.

In other words, what filthy input must my circuit deal with?

I'm sure I'll get a real spec eventually, but for now I'm putting together a block diagram so I'd like to get an idea of where to put in the various filters, emi junk, voltage protection, surge suppressors, etc.

Is there a 1-page AEC summary or something?

Comment: ISO 7637-2 and ISO 16750-2. Transil, caps, added zener protection, CLC pi filter, regulator...

Comment: AEC design is more of a book than 1 page.  Mechanical, Electrical, Climatic and Statistics with Company Quality Policies and Procedures to get certification.  Here's a few more pages in add. to the ISO specs. http://www.aecouncil.com/AECDocuments.html

Comment: Have a look at the LM2p3x(maybe LM29xx)  regulators which are designed for automotive environments. They list the key specs and probably cite references.

Comment: AEC Q100 || LM2931 example [**here**](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM2931-D.PDF) || DS says: 60 V Load Dump Protection, −50 V Reverse Transient Protection. "Designed primarily to survive in the harsh automotive environment, these devices will protect all external load circuitry from input fault conditions caused by reverse battery connection, two battery jump starts, and excessive line transients during load dump. ... series also includes internal current limiting, thermal shutdown, and additionally,
is able to withstand temporary power−up with mirror−image insertion."

Comment: LT - useful  [**Linear Technology Corporation
- Reliability Test Criteria For Automotive Grade Products **](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/quality/Automotive%20reliability%20test.pdf),